# white labeling a web app using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, branding

i am having a small custom built web app in PHP/MySql. i want to make it white label by allowing others (my selected clients) to point their subdomain to that app.

i have :
www.MainSite.ab and www.MainSiteAddonDomain.abc.ab

i want :
subdomain.myclientsite.com --> (mywebsite)/subfolder/

and address bar should show my clients url instead of my website like 
subdomain.myclient.com/subfolder/

what i did:
i added a (CNAME / A) record at myclient.com to my servers (domain / IP) and then in my main website i added a parked domain (subdomain.myclient.com) and then in manage redirected i redirected it to  /subfolder/

it all worked well BUT

if i open subdomain.myclient.com/index.php then it would open www.MainSite.ab that i dont want to open since it exposes our brand and violate white labeling. (this could be possible via .htaccess i guess)

what is the right way to achieve this ? since parked domains home directory is always at main domains home directory.

---

one thing more, the www.mainsite.ab/subfolder/ includes some library resources that are placed at www.mainsite.ab/library/ folder.

Comment: i added a cname/a record at my clients domain dns and pointed to my servers ip

Comment: is something missing ? or my method is wrong ? no replies or feedback ?